# Python creating objects

Tags: python, class, oop

The essential properties of a Thing are as follows :

1. The constructor should take in 1 parameter, the name of the Thing.

stone = Thing ('stone ')

2. owner : an attribute that stores the owner object of the Thing, usually a Person object.

In OOP, we set this attribute to None during initialization when this Thing does not belong to any Person yet (to signify the absence of an object value).

stone . owner

**None**

3. is_owned(): returns a boolean value, True if the thing is “owned” and False otherwise.

stone . is_owned ()

**False**

4.get_owner(): returns the Person object who owns the Thing object.

stone . get_owner ()

**None**

Implement the class Thing such that it satisfies the above properties and methods.

im not sure what is wrong with my code:

```
class Thing:
def __init__(self,name):
    self.name=name
    self.owner=None

def is_owned(self):
    return self.owner!=None
def get_owner(self):
    return self.owner
```

**My question**:
as the question states, when i input stone.owner, i expect to receive an output None. however, there is no output at all.
edit: no output received is accepted instead of None. However, is there any way to return None from stone.owner?

Comment: I am not sure but, you wanted method `is_owned` but you have in your code `is_owner`. Tell please what exactly is wrong, what output you are getting, and what output you would like to get.

Comment: you missed self in your method, and remember the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you are writing python code, you need to care about indentation.
2. Every function within a class needs `self` as parameter.

So, your code must be:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.owner="None"

    def is_owned(self):
        return self.owner!="None"
    def get_owner(self):
        return self.owner
```

Comment: A bit pedantic but - `self` as an argument is just a convention it could be called anything. Instance methods receive the `instance` as a the first parameter (usually called `self`), `classmethods` receive the `class` as the first parameter (usually called `cls`) and `staticmethods` receive nothing.

Comment: Thank you, @AChampion ! I didn't know that!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer using a property with getter.

```
class Thing(object):

        def __init__(self, name):

            self.name = name

            self.owner = None

           

        @property

        def isOwned(self):

            return self.owner is not None

   

    thing = Thing('stone')

   

    print("owner:", thing.owner)

    print("isOwned:", thing.isOwned)

 

    print("Setting owner.")   

    thing.owner = "Silver"

    print("owner:", thing.owner)

    print("isOwned:", thing.isOwned)
```

Output is like this:

```
$ python3 ./thingclass.py

owner: None

isOwned: False

Setting owner.

owner: Silver

isOwned: True
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason nothing is printed is most likely that the Python REPL does not print `None` values.
The current code in the question is better than the accepted answer (except for the indentation) because `None` is a singular value in Python, while `"None"` is an ordinary string (which is neither equal to `None` nor treated as a `False` value, both of which are true for `None`).